# Unable to access Heroku config vars from Django settings.py

Tags: django, heroku, settings, config

I have some config vars set on Heroku as described here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars. 
When I run:

```
heroku config
```

I see the config var in the list:

```
COMPRESS_OFFLINE:                  True
```

and I can run

```
heroku config:get COMPRESS_OFFLINE
```

and I get:

```
True
```

In my Django settings.py, I have:

```
import os
COMPRESS_OFFLINE = os.environ['COMPRESS_OFFLINE']
```

This is how the article linked above tells you to access Heroku config variables in Django. I have this config var set in my local .env file, and I can run foreman locally. But, when I deploy to Heroku, I get this error during deploy:

```
KeyError: 'COMPRESS_OFFLINE'
!     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app
```

I have the feeling I'm missing something painfully obvious, any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got an answer back from Heroku support that environment variables are not available during slug compilation by default. But, there is an experimental feature called user-env-compile that will make them available: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/labs-user-env-compile

I didn't need this, though. I thought that because it couldn't find them during compile that it wouldn't be able to find them at all. But, I found that they are available after compile. So, I just updated settings.py to have:

```
COMPRESS_OFFLINE = os.environ.get('COMPRESS_OFFLINE', True)
```

So that it defaults to True during compile when the environment variable is not available.

Comment: Is there a solution to this using node? Stuck on the same issue.