# Configuring Postgres on Heroku with Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku

I am trying to link a Heroku Postgres databse with my Django application. I have created the database and linked it to my Heroku application using [this tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql). I can't seem to get it working with Django, however.

I am able to access the database through the `heroku pg:psql` command. But when I try to run `python manage.py migrate`, Django gives...

```
settings.DATABASES is improperly configured

Please supply the ENGINE value.
```

In settings.py, I have...

```
import dj_database_url

DATABASES = {
    'default': dj_database_url.config(default=os.getenv('DATABASE_URL'))
}
```

I have already promoted the correct heroku postgres database to my app's `DATABASE_URL` variable, which I can verify through `heroku config`.

Comment: What output does `dj_database_url.config` provide when you run say `print`). Compare that to what django expects because we don't know what environment settings you have.

Comment: `default=os.getenv('DATABASE_URL')` is `None`. Why might that be? It shows up just fine in `heroku config`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heroku config variables aren't available in Django settings.py when testing locally.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21763381/3783608

Answer (score 1):

You've misread the instructions. It should be:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': dj_database_url.config()
}
```

dj_database_url already parses the env var, you don't need to pass it explicitly.